# kube-prometheus-config additionalScrapeConfig with value from values.yaml

Tags: prometheus

I am using kube-prometheus-stack with Helm for setting up Promtheus and Grafana . Deployment looks good but

1. I have my application pod running with a name that is chosen by user in values.yaml .. for example

valaues.yaml

```
application_namespace: application
```

While giving additionalScrapeConfig in prometheus, I want to give this namespace

values.yaml

```
kube-prometheus-stack:
  prometheus:
    prometheusSpec:
      additionalScrapeConfigs: |
             - job_name: "config"
               kubernetes_sd_config:
               - role: pod
                 namespaces:
                 names:
                   - {{ .Values.application_namespace }}
```

{{ .Values.application_namespace }} doesn't work. How can I get the role dynamic namespacevalue ?

Thank you.